# how to uncheck the radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

i am developing an quiz based app. there will be 1 quest and 4 opt(radio buttons) when user opens this app radio button will be unchecked but the prob comes when the user answers 1 quest and when he goes for next quest radio button will be checked.I want to uncheck/reset the radio buttons for every quest.How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using Custom List or other thing to make your desire View ,in this c you need to save position for Each Question answer if user has given answer by selecting RadioButton then make that Save in Some Like in `ArrayList` just for example.For next Question which have not been given answer you can make -1 flag for that next Question.

Below is code example which i use .

```
                 if (childData == -1) {
            mchildHolder.mRadioPass.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioCorrect.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioFail.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioNa.setChecked(false);

        } else if (childData == 0) {
            mchildHolder.mRadioPass.setChecked(true);
            mchildHolder.mRadioCorrect.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioFail.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioNa.setChecked(false);
        } else if (childData == 1) {
            mchildHolder.mRadioPass.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioCorrect.setChecked(true);
            mchildHolder.mRadioFail.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioNa.setChecked(false);
        } else if (childData == 2) {
            mchildHolder.mRadioPass.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioCorrect.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioFail.setChecked(true);
            mchildHolder.mRadioNa.setChecked(false);
        } else if (childData == 3) {
            mchildHolder.mRadioOn.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioOff.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioFail.setChecked(false);
            mchildHolder.mRadioNa.setChecked(true);
        }
```

above code is example which  can make your desire thing.
Let me known if you have doubt.