# Custom RadioButton within RadioGroup not having exclusive selection

Tags: android, radio-button, android-xml

I am trying to implement a custom `RadioButton`, and the styling is working as I would expecting, however, the selection highlighting is not exclusive. Meaning, I can have two buttons within the same group highlighted at the same time.

**Edit**
This the state **before** I select the second button:

[image]

This a visual of the issue I'm getting - note I'd only like one selected:

[image]

Below is the code for the background selector of my `RadioButton`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_selected"/>

    <item 
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_unselected"/>

    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_selected"/>

    <item 
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Below is my implementation in the group:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Test" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Test1" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Any thoughts?

**Edit**
Drawables:

toggle_button_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/dark_purple" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dark_purple" />
</shape>
```

toggle_button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/purple" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dark_purple" />
</shape>
```

Comment: @ArtooDetoo hmmm didn't help

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I wish...I just edited my post with the initial state before I press anything

Comment: Just tried it. Same issue. It seems like the selector is not picking up on the checked="false" event or something.

Comment: Now this is really very strange. The only thing I can think of (but I'd be surprised if it works so) is that the RadioButtons should have different ids?

Comment: I just figured that out from this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558045/radiobuttons-dont-properly-select-deselect-in-dynamically-created-radiogroup?rq=1! that was the issue!. If you put your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the RadioButtons should have different ids.